# Select next row programmatically

Tags: ios, tableview

How can I select the next row programmatically in iOS?

I have a nextButton on my view, and I want myTable to select the next row after clicking my nextButton.

```
[myTable selectRowAtIndexPath: ??????
                 animated:YES 
           scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

is my code is correct?

Comment: Can you explain where is your button? Inside a cell, or outside the tableview? Do you store the currently selected indexPath already somewhere in a property or ivar?

Comment: My button is outside of the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable with your current index of the table

```
long currentindex;
```

Create index path and select row as your code :

```
currentindex = currentindex +1;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentindex inSection:0];
[myTable selectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath
                 animated:YES 
           scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```